# array sum-up and traversal issue

Tags: php

I have a 3rd party app, whose API return data in form of array as:

```
Array
(
[2011-03-26] => Array
    (
    )

[2011-03-27] => Array
    (
    )

[2011-03-28] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [label] => apples
                [eaten] => 2
                [noteaten] => 2
                [rotten] => 2
            )

    )

[2011-03-29] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [label] => apples
                [eaten] => 2
                [noteaten] => 2
                [rotten] => 7
            )

    )

[2011-03-30] => Array
    (
    )

[2011-03-31] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [label] => apples
                [eaten] => 1
                [noteaten] => 1
                [rotten] => 4
            )

    )

[2011-04-01] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [label] => bananas
                [eaten] => 18
                [noteaten] => 18
                [rotten] => 18
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [label] => apples
                [eaten] => 6
                [noteaten] => 7
                [rotten] => 31
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [label] => oranges
                [eaten] => 1
                [noteaten] => 1
                [rotten] => 9
            )

    )

[2011-04-02] => Array
    (
    )

[2011-04-03] => Array
    (
    )

[2011-04-04] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [label] => bananas
                [eaten] => 24
                [noteaten] => 27
                [rotten] => 27
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [label] => apples
                [eaten] => 2
                [noteaten] => 3
                [rotten] => 8
            )

    )

)
```

Now, I need to find out total eaten and not-eaten for each fruit (i.e, label here) over the particular course of time like

```
fruit              eaten               noteaten 
------------------------------------------------
apples              15                   20
bananas             30                   12
```

I have written 2 foreach loops: first one for outer array (one which have dates as key), and another one for each date (see 2011-04-01, it has 3 sub-elements)

but this solution is not optimal. It takes lots of time.

Is there any other way to achieve following? Any optimal way?

EDIT: This is just a sample data, original data may span upto 100 or more days. At that time process takes lots of time.

EDIT 2:

$result is where I get my data from 3rd party API

```
$output_arr = array();

foreach($result as $date_arr) {
 foreach ($date_arr as $date_values) {
     if (isset($output_arr[$date_values['label']]))
        $output_arr[$date_values['label']] += $date_values['eaten'];
     else
        $output_arr[$date_values['label']] = $date_values['eaten'];
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the timing problem is in your code and not in the 3:d party app? 
What is an acceptable execution time?
Could you attach a copy of the code you've tried? 

Even for thousands of days with thousands of sub-elements, this should be possible to do quickly.

Comment: Yes, timing problem is with the code, and not with 3rd party app. I'll do put up the code in few mins.

Comment: Perhaps this sort of processing could be done as a job, and the results could be cached for later retrieval. If it's taking exceedingly long this may be a good idea, especially if this process is running for multiple web requests.

Comment: I seriously seriously doubt that it's your code that's slowing you down considerably. Some consider that PHP doesn't loop well but 100s of rows is not going to make it sweat. Have you tried debugging your code to see where it gets slow?

Comment: @TomcatExodus: I cannot process this as job

Comment: @JohnP: I tried to debug it, but I don't see anything unusual.

Comment: do anyone here think that my code lacks something, or something that can be done to improve it?

Comment: @I-M-JM: Well, either way; consider caching the process results anyways. Pending on how often values may be updated, likelihood is there would be considerable redundancy on processing this for every page request, given this is occurring on page requests.

Comment: @I-M-JM I meant that did you see where it's getting slow. Does your script take an unusually long time to complete? Try using `microtime` to find out where the time is being spent : http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: I tried with microtime, here are the results:

API call: 0.24431109428406
Processing: 0.00028014183044434  What can be done now ?

Comment: I'm confused. How fast do you want this be?

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be in the 3:d party app. Can you replace it? Can you run it on a faster machine? Do you need live data from it, or can you cache a result thats computed regulary? Why is `0.3s` not fast enough?

Comment: I think 0.3s is the third party app, just tested the code supplied by you anders, it takes ~55s on my machine.

Comment: Made a function that does the traversal in ~5s. Check it out and comment if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Check the function `sumIt_walk`. It saves a static array where it builds the output and gives a simple mechanism of retrieving it. using `array_walk` traversal goes down to **<5s** for the test case where foreach does **60s**, on an array with 1.000.000 items.

After seeing the above test case takes ~1minute to complete, I realized the approach was fundamentally flawed. I suspected the reason the array takes so long is due to memory swaps([further reading if you're interested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080198/how-does-php-handle-variables-in-ram)), I took the liberty of making a recursive function to pass to array_walk() that speeds up the process considerably (~5s as opposed to ~55).

```
function sumIt_walk($item,$key,$return=false){
    static $sum=array();
    if($return){
        // just to make it reusable
        $r=$sum;
        $sum=array();
        return $r;
    }
    if(!isset($item['label']))return array_walk($item,'sumIt_walk');
    $key=$item['label'];
    if(!isset($sum[$key]))$sum[$key]=array(0,0);
    $sum[$key][0]+=$item['eaten'];
    $sum[$key][1]+=$item['noteaten'];
}
```

I have also created 3 test cases with different approaches. The third one being a direct recursive function that's not passed being passed to array_walk. The results are remarkable:

```
Rendering sample array took 4.257504940033 s.


TEST CASE: foreach
apples 16668129 16665262
bananas 16656715 16659333
oranges 16676978 16668761
Traversing array took 68.361897945404 s.
Output took 1.3828277587891E-5 s.


TEST CASE: array_walk
apples 16668129 16665262
bananas 16656715 16659333
oranges 16676978 16668761
Traversing array took 3.6125140190125 s.
Output took 1.3113021850586E-5 s.


TEST CASE: recursive
apples 16668129 16665262
bananas 16656715 16659333
oranges 16676978 16668761
Traversing array took 53.461534976959 s.
Output took 1.3828277587891E-5 s.
```

As you can see `array_walk` slices of 50s from the traversal time. Goes to show, built-in functions are awesome.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1G');
echo'<pre>';

function getSampleArray($days, $postsperday){
    $arr=array();
    $fruits=array('apples','bananas','oranges');
    for($i=0;$i<$days;$i++){
        $thisday=array();
        for($j=0;$j<$postsperday;$j++){
            $thisday[$j]=array('label'=>$fruits[rand(0,2)], 
                        'eaten'=>rand(0,100), 
                        'noteaten'=>rand(0,100), 
                        'rotten'=>rand(0,100));
        }
        $arr[date('Ymd',$i*60*60*24)]=$thisday;
    }
    return $arr;
}

function sumIt($arr, $return=false){
    static $sum=array();
    if($return){
        // just to make it reusable
        $r=$sum;
        $sum=array();
        return $r;
    }
    if(!isset($arr['label'])){
        foreach($arr as $data)sumIt($data);
        return;
    }
    $key=$arr['label'];
    if(!isset($sum[$key]))$sum[$key]=array(0,0);
    $sum[$key][0]+=$arr['eaten'];
    $sum[$key][1]+=$arr['noteaten'];
}

function sumIt_walk($item,$key,$return=false){
    static $sum=array();
    if($return){
        // just to make it reusable
        $r=$sum;
        $sum=array();
        return $r;
    }
    if(!isset($item['label']))return array_walk($item,'sumIt_walk');
    $key=$item['label'];
    if(!isset($sum[$key]))$sum[$key]=array(0,0);
    $sum[$key][0]+=$item['eaten'];
    $sum[$key][1]+=$item['noteaten'];
}

$timer=microtime(true);
$result=getSampleArray(1000,1000);
$rendersampledata=microtime(true)-$timer;

echo 'Rendering sample array took '.$rendersampledata.' s.'."\n";

$testCases=array('foreach','array_walk','recursive');
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $output_arr=array();
    $timer=microtime(true);
    switch($i){
    case'0':
        foreach($result as $date_arr) {
            foreach ($date_arr as $date_values) {
                if (isset($output_arr[$date_values['label']])){
                    $output_arr[$date_values['label']][0] += $date_values['eaten'];
                    $output_arr[$date_values['label']][1] += $date_values['noteaten'];
                }else{
                    $output_arr[$date_values['label']][0] = $date_values['eaten'];
                    $output_arr[$date_values['label']][1] = $date_values['eaten'];
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case'1':
        array_walk($result,'sumIt_walk');
        $output_arr=sumIt_walk(null,null,true);
        break;
    case'2':
        sumIt($result);
        $output_arr=sumIt(null,true);
        break;
    }

    $traversearray = microtime(true) - $timer;
    $timer = microtime(true);

    foreach ($output_arr as $label => $value){
        echo $label.' '.$value[0].' '.$value[1]."\n";
    }
    $outputtime = microtime(true) - $timer;
    echo 'Traversing array took '.$traversearray.' s. In test case '.$testCases[$i]."\n";
    echo 'Output took '.$outputtime.' s. In test case '.$testCases[$i]."\n";
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

If you can slice even more computational time from that function, I urge you to post it here so we can have a reference.

P.S. I thought about creating mix-matches of the three test-cases (foreach-recursive, array_walk-foreach,etc) But `array_walk` just seems to blow everything away and not merit any new test cases.

Comment: time of execution, when I am using foreach loop: 4.6968460083008E-5

Comment: time of execution, when I am using array walk: 0.00016999244689941

Comment: I want to know which I should use, foreach loop or arraywalk? I don't know what E-5 means?

Comment: 4.6968460083008E-5 = 4.696 *10^-5 => ~0.00005. You are trying to find better code for something that takes works faster than a ms? For larger arrays you can see array_walk works better due how memory works in PHP. For your scenario, keep code readable and use the foreach.

Comment: I have tried now with very very large array, and found array_walk to be faster compared to foreach

Comment: so I have decided to go with the following: if array have total keys less than 50, foreach otherwise array_walk

Comment: Everyone here thought that you were working with large arrays, hence the question.

Comment: Hahaha, I think you should look more on the hundreds, since in the test scenario Anders used, he had 1000 days with 1000 items per day.

Comment: yup, you are right. I think I should go for atleast 50000000 keys with foreach

Comment: Erm, 1000*1000 = 1 mil, if you do foreach till 5mil, you will clearly get to 60s of usage time... Anyway, outside the scope of your original question. If you ever update the function or make a better one, update the code!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your implementation is close to the optimum *given the data structure at hand*. When I try this test script for various number of days and number of sub-arrays per day, I get a consistent linear behavior of approx. `5µs`per sub-array on my machine.

You can try this yourself by adjusting the settings in the call to `getSampleArray`.

```
function getSampleArray($days, $postsperday)
{
    $arr = Array();
    $fruits = Array("apples","bananas","oranges");
    for($i=0;$i<$days;$i++) 
    {
        $thisday = Array();
        for($j=0;$j < $postsperday;$j++)
        {
            $thisday[$j] = Array("label" => $fruits[rand(0,2)], 
                        "eaten" => rand(0,100), 
                        "noteaten" => rand(0,100), 
                        "rotten" => rand(0,100));
        }       
        $arr[date("Ymd",$i*60*60*24)] = $thisday;
    }   
    return $arr;
}

$timer = microtime(true);
$result = getSampleArray(1000,1000);
$rendersampledata = microtime(true) - $timer;

$output_arr = Array();

$timer = microtime(true);
$x = 0;
foreach($result as $date_arr) {
 foreach ($date_arr as $date_values) {
     if (isset($output_arr[$date_values['label']]))
        $output_arr[$date_values['label']] += $date_values['eaten'];
     else
        $output_arr[$date_values['label']] = $date_values['eaten'];
 }
}

$traversearray = microtime(true) - $timer;
$timer = microtime(true);
foreach ($output_arr as $label => $value)
{
    echo "$label\t$value\n";
}
$outputtime = microtime(true) - $timer;
echo "\n";
echo "Rendering sample array took $rendersampledata s.\n";
echo "Traversing array took $traversearray s.\n";
echo "Output took $outputtime s.\n";
```